# XML signing with x509Certificate code in 'C'

Tags: xml, x509certificate, xml-signature

XML signing with 509 certification
Hello,
I need to develop code which will sign, and verify, a XML message. Once its signed the signing has to be certifies with a 509 certificate. There seems to be a reasonably good amount of information on the web about doing all this in C# or Java which I can use for test purposes, but I need to develop my main code in 'C' and it has to be light weight and free from dll's. 
I found one website www.aleksey.com which does have some code I could use, but it seems quite heavy and I needs something more stripped down and light weight. 
I was using TinyXML to do the original XML parsing but that doesn't seem to have a signing part to it.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction or to the right website, any information I would be very greatful.

Also as I'm quite stupid any one know of a step by step guide as to what is actually happening?

Thanks.

Dan.

Comment: https://github.com/leethomason/tinyxml2 hope this will help for some understanding :)

Comment: Tiny XML doesn't seem to do signing?

Comment: deeply i'm not aware with tiny xml but i refer that code once and for downloading that code which i give you link that not require any signin

Answer (score 0):

XML Signature is somewhat complex in itself and in my opinion [XML Security Library](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/index.html) is as light weight as it can be and can be compiled statically - checkout the [FAQ](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/faq.html). After all [simple example](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/api/xmlsec-examples-sign-template-file.html) is 200ish lines of code. If you can use C++ one alternative would be [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/cprogramming.html).